# Finding out if a point is within a line with a given width

Tags: math

I'm a little lost on the math aspect if what I need to do.

I have 3 points: Point A, Point B, Point C.

I need to find out if point C is on the line segment from Point A to Point B. But... the caveat is that I at the same time need to make the line "wider" from Point A to B.

I'm guessing I need to first create a bounding box that surrounds A->B? Then check if I'm within the bounding box?

How do I go about creating that box..

A and B can negative or positive on the grid, and the "distance" of the box is changeable as well.

I'm hoping this picture illustrates it better. The distance is the total given, so half would go 1 direction, half the other.

[image]

Even if I can just get those 4 points of the box, I can do the simple check to see if C is within.

Comment: This is a programming site not a math site.  If you have a math question then you should try [Math.SE](http://math.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Rotate the point in such a way that the rectangle becomes axis-aligned. Then it's just a simple axis-aligned rectangle. Breaking down the problem in this way also allows you to easily adapt the strategy for other geometry.

Answer (score 2):

Define `u = normalize(b - a)` and `v = (-u.y, u.x)`.

Your point `c` is inside the line segment from `a` to `b` of width `w` if and only if both of the following hold:

- `0 <= dot(c - a, u) <= length(b - a)`
- `abs(dot(c - a, v)) < w / 2`

Answer (score 1):

You have to *(web picture with another point names P0=A, P1=B, P=C)*:

[image]

1) make orthogonal projection of C onto AB line (point D)
2) find distance CD and check if it is less than half-width
3) check that D lies between A and B (inside the segment)

for 2: distance `d = |AC x uAB|` - norm of cross product of AC vector and unit direction vector `uAB = AB/|AB|`

for 3: true if `DotProduct(AC, AB) >= 0` and `DotProduct(BC, BA) >= 0`

Answer (score 0):

Here you have all necessary formulas https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_from_a_point_to_a_line

First you find shortest distance btw point C and the line and check that it is less equal that width/2. Then you find coordinates of point D - closest to C point on the line and check that this point is between A and B. Than can be done by checking that distance(A,D) + distance(B,D) == distance( A,B )